# Show data from controller to view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

in there i want to show data from my controller to my view but i geting error. so now i want to ask how ? let me show my code.

this my controller :

```
public function getBulan($nama)
    {

        $data['users'] = DB::table('lembur_karyawan')
                ->select('nama', DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( total ) ) ) as   total_lembur'))
                ->groupBy('nama')
                ->havingRaw('SUM(total)')
                ->get();

        return view('bulan_user',$data);
    }
```

and this is my view :

```
<?php echo $users->{'total_lembur'} ?>
```

[image: what i want]
[image: other table if i use first();]

have someone know how ? i have no idea how to do it .

Answer (score 1):

No need to use  variable `data`.

Use like,

```
$users = DB::table('lembur_karyawan')
            ->select('nama', DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( total ) ) ) as   total_lembur'))
            ->groupBy('nama')
            ->havingRaw('SUM(total)')
            ->get();

return view('bulan_user', ['users' => $users]);
```

Print it in your view like,

```
@foreach($users as $user)    

 {{ $user->total_lembur }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: i getting error :

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lembur\resources\views\tanggale.blade.php)

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compact`also like this:

```
public function getBulan($nama)
{

    $users = DB::table('lembur_karyawan')
            ->select('nama', DB::raw('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( total ) ) ) as   total_lembur'))
            ->groupBy('nama')
            ->havingRaw('SUM(total)')
            ->get();

    return view('bulan_user', compact('users'));
}
```

In the `view`:

```
{{ $user->total_lembur }}
```

Comment: i getting error : Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lembur\resources\views\tanggale.blade.php) what should i do ?

Comment: `dd($users);` into the method. Then post the output here.

Answer (score 0):

Do what @Md Mahfuzur Rahman has suggested.

Then in the view, you will have to run a foreach loop.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->total_lembur }}
@endforeach
```